# Rails Arel equivalent of this complex sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

Here is the original logic

```
(scrape_datas = ScrapeData.find(
  :all, :conditions => 
  "artist_status = 'NOT_FOUND' 
   AND blacklisted = 1 
   AND extracted = 0 
   and not EXISTS(
     SELECT * FROM artist_name_suggestions where original = artist_name
   )
```

I've been able to split up the first part better

```
scrape_datas = ScrapeData.where(
  :artist_status => 'NOT_FOUND',
  :blacklisted   => 1,
  :extracted     => 0
)
```

Although having issues getting the "and not EXISTS" query into the mix

```
and not EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM artist_name_suggestions where original = artist_name
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can extract simple scopes:

```
scope :not_found, where(:artist_status => 'NOT_FOUND')
scope :blacklisted, where(:blacklisted => 1)
scope :extracted, where(:extracted => 0)
```

Then add a query method (assume artist_name is a column of scrape_datas):

```
def self.no_suggestions
  scrape_datas = ScrapeData.arel_table
  suggestions = ArtistNameSuggestion.arel_table
  where(ArtistNameSuggestion.where(
    suggestions[:original].eq(scrape_datas[:artist_name])
  ).exists.not)
end
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
ScrapeData.not_found.blacklisted.extracted.no_suggestions
```

Comment: Great,  and this works beautiful in Rails 3 (As I tested).  Although unfortunately the app this needs to incorporate with is rails 2.3.5.  I have fake-arel which can handle the scope, although since I don't have access to Arel (I can't do arel_table).   Any idea how this could be done with Rails 2.3.5?